# angularjs firebase authentication example for a web app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need an example of how to implement user authentication and role-based authentication in angular firebase. I am using angular 1 but there is no perfect tutorial for user authentication in angular1 with ifrebase. All I am getting is Angular2 example. Can somebody help me with a perfect example based on roles like user and admin?